# Jquery Watermark not working in HTML page

Tags: jquery, html

I have an HTML page. I want to implement watermark functionality on textboxes, but it is not working. Dont know the reason why, I tried with many things but couldn't. See my code for your reference:

```
  <style type="text/css">
    input.watermark {
        color: #999;
    }

    //light silver color
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var watermark = 'Puts your text here';
        $('#txtNameWaterMark').val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
        //if blur and no value inside, set watermark text and class again.
        $('#txtNameWaterMark').blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).val(watermark).addClass('watermark');
            }
        });
        $('#txtNameWaterMark').focus(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == watermark) {
                $(this).val('').removeClass('watermark');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Also, Please find the HTML of the textboxes for your reference:-

```
<div class="contacttext">
<div class="errors">
    <ul></ul>
</div>
<div class="contactMain">
    <div class="contactName">Name</div>
    <div class="contactformfield">
        <!--<input name="txtName" type="text" class="textboxEffect" id="txtName" value="" /><span class="errortext">*</span> -->

        <input type="text" id="txtNameWaterMark" class="textboxEffect" /><span class="errortext">*</span>
    </div>
    <div id="nameError" class="red">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="contactName">Contact</div>
    <div class="contactformfield">
        <input name="txtName" type="text" id="txtNameWaterMark2" value="Enter Your Name" class="textboxEffect" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="contactName">Email</div>
    <div class="contactformfield">
        <input name="txtName" type="text" value="Enter Your Name" class="textboxEffect" />
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="contactName">Comments</div>
    <div class="contactformfield">
        <textarea name="" cols="" rows="" class="txtarea-postnow"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <br />

    <div class="contactName">&nbsp;</div>

    <div class="contactformfield">
        <input type="submit" name="save" value="Submit" class="button" />
        <input type="button" name="btnReset" value="Reset" id="btnReset" class="button" />
    </div>
</div>

</form>
```

Comment: It seems that you have watermark and placeholder confused, is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/17kz67kL/) what you want?

Comment: @PatsyIssa placeholder attribute doesn't work in old IEs

Comment: @PatsyIssa: The thing which you showed is exactly what I want. But My watermark is not working for the textbox,.

Comment: As @PatsyIssa stated, you went the long way around. may as well go with the "placeholder" attribute instead of the JQuery route

Comment: @Pye Microsoft discontinued old IEs [move on already](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder).

Comment: @Saba [works on textarea as well](http://jsfiddle.net/17kz67kL/1/)

Comment: @PatsyIssa: let me try, as I tried it but it didn't worked

Comment: @PatsyIssa: Please put an answer for it, so that I mark it as an answer

Comment: @Saba sure thing just one sec writing up a non-jquery solution for old browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments you really don't need jquery as input/textareas have the placeholder attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="txtNameWaterMark" class="textboxEffect" placeholder="Placeholder text here..." />
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/17kz67kL/)

Now if you must support [old browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) here's a [polyfill](http://jamesallardice.github.io/Placeholders.js/) to make the attribute work doing this with jquery is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

AS Patsy Issa pointed out in comments, you may want to use the HTML5 **placeholder** attribute instead of handmade jquery functions :

```
<input type="text" id="txtNameWaterMark" class="textboxEffect" placeholder="whatever text you want" />
```

---

This is mainly supported, except on old IEs (how astonishing !). 
Nevertheless, since you're already using jQuery on your page, you can use this [jQuery plugin](https://mths.be/placeholder) that make it supported on every browser :

```
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder="e.g. John Doe">
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="e.g. address@example.ext">
<input type="url" name="url" placeholder="e.g. http://mathiasbynens.be/">
<input type="tel" name="tel" placeholder="e.g. +32 472 77 69 88">
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="e.g. h4x0rpr00fz">
<input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search this site…">
<textarea name="message" placeholder="Your message goes here"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('input, textarea').placeholder();
</script>
```

Comment: How is this simpler or more effective the @PatsyIssa answer? Stop trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @skibbi_bizzle Well Pasty Issa posted his older browser support polyfill after my answer. How could I know his method could/would be better ?

Comment: Even without the polyfill, as he stated, they removed support for old IE... It isn't necessary to post work around's for old browsers.

Comment: @skibbi_bizzle Removing support for old IE doesn't mean everyone stops using it. I work with big companies which still use IE 6 and ask for IE6 compatibility. I assume I'm not alone on the web in that case - that's why people make solutions to support older browsers.